# Unable to Understand the below statements of models in Django

Tags: django, orm

I am naive in Django, I have done a sample E-commerce application that is present online. I am unable to understand the highlighted statements, I searched online but unable to understand the statements.

Can someone please explain me like below

**productitems = self.name_set.all()**

From where this name_set.all() came ?????????

**orderItems = self.orderitem_set.all()**

likewise from where orderitem_set.all() ?????????

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
      email = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

      def __str__(self):
             return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    #image
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

    @property
    def get_product_total(self):
        **productitems = **self.name_set.all()****
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in productitems])
        return total
        print('total:',total)



class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        orderItems = **self.orderitem_set.all()**
        for i in orderItems:
            if i.product.digital == False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()

        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        print(self.product.price)
        #  print("self.product.price:",self.product.price)
       # print("self.quantity:", self.quantity)
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.address)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are reverse foreign key lookups. The `{field_name}_set` pattern is what Django uses by default if you don't define a different term yourself.

The Django documentation explains it more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

and here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

An example from the docs is:

```
>>> b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b.entry_set.all() # Returns all Entry objects related to Blog.
```

Instead of using the default you can set the related lookup to a custom value when defining the ForeignKey field on the model, using the `related_name` argument. I do this often myself, there are usually more fitting terms for the project than the default.

Comment: Thank you @rup, i have gone through the 2nd link relationships-backward they have explained very well.